# Win condition method for tic tac toe not working only on the second row

Tags: java

I have a tic tac toe game using gridlayout to arrange buttons in a 3x3 grid, my problem is with a method called public void checkWinRowX(), in my active listeners for my buttons whenever a button is pressed it adds 5 to both the colum int and the row int for which ever row/col they're in. and the method for checking for x win is checking for a row to be equal to 15, then highlighting the three x

to recreate the problem use the full code link at the bottom, then put three x's in the middle row, they're supposed to highlight when there's three in a row but they don't.

these are the active listeners that affect the second row:

```
private class twoOneListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
          if(four)
              getTurn(twoOnebutton);
              four = false;
              String twoOneString = twoOnebutton.getText().toString();      
              if (twoOneString.equals("X"))
              {
                     if(x4 == 0)
                     {
                      colOne += 5;
                      rowTwo += 5;
                     }
                     x4++;
                     checkWinColumX();
                     checkWinRowX();      
              }     
        }
   }

             //******2,2*********//
   private class twoTwoListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
             if(five)
              getTurn(twoTwobutton);
              five = false;
              String twoTwoString = oneTwobutton.getText().toString();      
              if (twoTwoString.equals("X"))
              {
                  if(x5 == 0)
                  {  
                     colTwo += 5; 
                     rowTwo += 5;   
                  } 
                     x5++;
                     checkWinColumX();
                     checkWinRowX();      
              }   
        }
   }

            //******2,3*********//
   private class twoThreeListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {

              if(six)
              getTurn(twoThreebutton);
              six = false;
              String twoThreeString = twoThreebutton.getText().toString();      
              if (twoThreeString.equals("X"))
              {
                  if(x6 == 0)
                     {  
                     colThree += 5; 
                     rowTwo += 5;    
                     }
                     x6++;
                     checkWinColumX();
                     checkWinRowX();      
              }
           }           
      }
```

and this is the check row method:

```
public void checkWinRowX()
             {
               if(gameWon = false); 
               {
                  //first row
                  if(rowOne == 15)
                  {
                     oneOnebutton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                     oneTwobutton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                     oneThreebutton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                  }
                  //Second row
                  if(rowTwo == 15)
                  {
                     twoOnebutton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                     twoTwobutton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                     twoThreebutton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                  }
                  //Third row
                  if(rowThree == 15)
                  {
                     threeOnebutton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                     threeTwobutton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                     threeThreebutton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                  }
               }
           }
```

full code here: https://pastebin.com/rYXrx3m4

Comment: do everyone a favor and format your code

Comment: `if(gameWon = false);` shouldn't that be `if(gameWon == false);`?

Comment: edit: wait nvm sorry didn't realize i had still had that, sorry I don't get much time to work on this project for school so I missed that I'll fix that

Comment: I pinpointed the problem in the code by printing rowTwo, it's something to do with twoTwo's active listener, both twoOne and twoThree add 5 to rowTwo, but twoTwo isnt adding 5 to rwoTwo so it wont highlight as won.

Comment: btw the `;` after the `if` voids the if-statement as the `;` is an empty statement. The `{` `}` block will this way always be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, twoTwos active listener wasn't the same as the others, idk what was different but I copied and pasted another listener into it and changed the objects

fixed :)